# A word meaning to make a task so difficult that it is practically impossible

Tags: single-word-requests

As the title says, I am trying to find a verb that means intentionally obstructing and making something so difficult that it is practically impossible to carry out. For context, I am speaking about voter suppression, and I was trying to think of the proper verb to represent the actions of Jim Crow laws on black voters; I came up with *obstruction* and *inhibition*, but neither is fully what I am looking for. The nuance in this case is that it is intentional of one entity to be doing this to another entity. Any ideas?

Comment: It would help if you could add a sentence with a blank to fill

Comment: The term ***impediment*** may be appropriate: 

 
*something that makes progress, movement, or achieving something difficult or impossible* https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/impediment?q=Impediment+

Comment: "Stymie" has the meaning of blocking or hindering. It may not have the connotations of premeditation that I think you're looking for, though.

Comment: Perhaps "crush" or "railroad" are worth considering. "Their efforts to vote were all but crushed by a system that was weighted against them."

Comment: "[constructive dismissal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_dismissal)" if it's in the workplace.

Comment: Are you looking for a noun or a verb? It seems like you are looking for a verb, but the examples you give are nouns.

Answer (score 1):

Three words come to mind

> Repress = to control what people do, especially by using force
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/repress)

> Inhibit = to take an action that makes something less likely to happen, or that discourages someone from doing something:
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inhibit)

> Stifle = to prevent something from happening, being expressed, or continuing:
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stifle)

Of these, I suggest *stifle* because it seems the most general of the three, without the specific overtones of force in *repress*, while including or implying the taking of actions as in *inhibit*. But the choice may be best informed by context.

The stifling of voting might then be done by *encumbering* the voting process.

> Encumber = to weigh someone or something down, or to make it difficult for someone to do something:
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/encumber)

Answer (score 0):

**"concealed prohibition"**, seems like a good fit.

e.g. "Abortion is legal throughout this country, even though accessbility varies from state to state. In some states, requirements are so severe and accessbility so scanty that you might as well call it **concealed prohibition.**"